# How to convert PDF text co-ordinates to image text co-ordinates in C#

Tags: c#, itext

I have a PDF file and I have extracted its text position co-ordinates using iTextSharp and have stored them in a JSON file like as follows:

```
[{"text":"New","top":1471.2,"left":528.72,"height":20.8999023,"width":45.6535645}]
```

I am using that text co-ordinate to highlight that area in image, but it's highlighting wrong area.
I want to convert those position co-ordinates for image.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://www.pdfscripting.com/public/PDF-Page-Coordinates.cfm

Comment: I want to convert the positions dynamically for images.

Comment: *"convert those position co-ordinates for image"* - what do you mean by that, what image?

Comment: @BRoy I did understand that. Note that I only posted a comment, not an answer. The referred document may help understand the coordinate system and thus positions in PDF files better.

Comment: My PDF file have been converted in JP2 image. The JSON data I shared above are the text position co-ordinates of PDF file. Now I want those texts' position co-ordinates in image please.